# Docker compose is not allowing a persitent dashboard folder

Tags: docker-compose, grafana

this part of a docker compose file works

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=grafana
    volumes:
      - ./grafana_data/datasources:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
      - grafana_dashboards:/var/lib/grafana
    ...
    ...
    
volumes:
  grafana_dashboards:
```

grafana_dashboards and grafana_data exists.

The datasources in ./grafana_data/datasources.yml are pulled correctly but complained as not writeable.

What ever I change here I get complains from docker compose.

How could I change this to correctly load dashboards and datasource in the grafana container with docker compose?

Comment: The last lines of docker-compose are missing.

Comment: @doneforaiur you mean where the three dots are or below volume ? there is not more to add from my side. what could be missing ?

Comment: No, the `volumes:` part cuts off. There should be `external: true` line. Also, could you check [this](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/16830) issue?

Comment: I did use the default path structure and it worked.. I'll check with absolute path

Comment: ok the volume thing is not the issue. changing to absolute path works fine but the complain is the same. Not writeable for datasource and the dashboards and the login does now not work at all

Comment: Just to be sure; could you connect to the `grafana` container via `docker execute -ti grafana bash` and run `chown -R grafana:grafana "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING" && chmod 777 "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING"`. This is the shared workaround in the issue I've shared. It seems that everything is correct, also checked [this](https://www.datamachines.io/blog/understanding-docker-volume-persisting-a-grafana-configuration-file) article which suggests same things. Interesting.

Comment: @doneforaiur thanks that is very probably a solution how would I do that with docker compose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meantime there is a solution as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1477291/grafana-provisioning-dashboards-in-docker)

Basically there was a confusion between the mapped folders and the paths in the config. Also grafana has a provision mechanism where

```
etc/grafana/provisioning/...
```

should be used.

The [grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#config-file-locations) is not clear about that.